# Filling containers in functions avoiding segmentation faults

Tags: c++, stl, scope, segmentation-fault

I come from Java, where filling containers did not involve thinking. My problem now that i work with c++ is, that filling a container in a function with data which is declared in function scope can lead to errors, where the data doesn't exist any more when I want to access it.
I could not find tutorials addressing the problem, so I went the Java way and only made containers getting pointers declared with "new". But now I am forced to return a

```
std::list<Vertex<float> >
```

from a function and thought this might be a good point to learn how I would fill and return such a thing. Would this

```
{
std::list<Vertex<float> > myList;
Vertex<float> v(0.0, 0.1, 0.2);
myList.push_back(v);
myList.push_back(Vertex<float>(1,0, 1.1, 1.2));
return myList;
}
```

actually be fine as a sample function body? And if yes, why would v still exist outside of the scope? Does each insertion in a container also imply a copying?

Comment: Yes. push_back does create a copy of the objects you insert. emplace_back in c++11 offers in place construction instead of copying.

Comment: v will not exist outside of the function. but change v won't change the value in myList. In C++11 , I think u cant visit v after moving to myList.

Comment: It's fine except for one minor detail: you almost certainly do *not* want to use `std::list` (while it *can* be useful, it's fairly uncommon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work "fine" since every operation there creates a copy.

- `myList.push_back(v);` creates a copy of `v` so that visiblity of `v` is now irrelevant.
- `return myList;` returns a copy of the list to the calling function so the visiblity of myList is now irrelevant. The calling function should make a copy of this list to keep it in scope, else it will be destroyed at the end of execution of the line that calls this function.

The reason that fine is quoted is that copies are typically expensive. In your case they are quite small so it might be irrelevant, and in many cases they might be optimised away, but it is still something to keep in mind.

**Old C++ way** of optimizing is to pass a list by reference and use that to construct your list, instead of returning by value.

```
void MakeMeAList(std::list<Vertex<float> >& aList){
    ....
}

std::list<Vertex<float> > aList;
MakeMeAList(aList);
```

As @billz suggests, [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) should optimize away the copies even if this is not done.

**New C++ (c++11) -**
The use of `emplace_back` to construct the list, would be more efficient that copying, as long as the input variables are not going to be used any more. ( thanks @Troy)

My C++11 is weak, I am almost sure even returning by value is OK since Move semantics would optimize it away, but I am only 95% sure.

Comment: how would I avoid copying in these cases? Pointers, again?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel you can avoid returning the list by passing it as a reference, and you can avoid coping the vectors by using `emplace_back` as @Troy suggests

Answer (score 1):

To add to Karthik's reply, if you're using a relatively new compiler that implements r-value references (part of C++0x standard), your approach will work perfectly without the negative impact of the copy operation.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors
for a brief intro to r-values.

Note that before r-value references were adopted, many compilers eliminated the 'expensive copy operation' involved in returning collections through what is called Return Value Optimization. Again Wiki has more details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Visual Studio 2005 (and newer) implements RVO, and I believe GCC also has a similar feature. So effectively, your code, which is more readable than using arguments to return values, is the correct approach and ought to work very well if you're using the latest compilers.